# Parser that accepts Scala Identifiers?

Tags: parsing, scala

I was wondering whether the standard Scala parser combinators contain a parser that accepts the same identifiers that the Scala language itself also accepts (as specified in the Scala Language Specification, Section 1.1).

The `StdTokenParsers` trait has an `ident` parser, but it rejects identifiers like `empty_?`.

(If there is indeed no such parser, I could also just instantiate the Scala parser itself, but that wouldn't be as lightweight anymore.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a standard parser combinator, but there are canonical tools for testing Scala id-ness in scala.tools.nsc.util.Chars. No need to instantiate either Global or a Scala scanner.